# C: how to use realloc on Strings properly in this program?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

The task is to make 2 different functions. 1 where malloc creates a length for char and put in their 2 Strings. The other function can't give a return type. It should change the lengh of the 2 fused Strings to fit in a 3rd one. But in some it doesn't give the results like it should. The first "Failure" should be one but the other 3 once shouldn't. My problem is that they get placed somewhere else in the system and somehow the pointer lose track.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concatStrings( char* concaStr,char*str);
void concatStrings2( char* newString,char*str);
void testConcatStrings(char* concaStr,char*str, char*str2, char*expected);
int main()
{
    char *str="Dynamic";
    testConcatStrings("Memory", str,"Management","DynamicMemoryManagement");
    testConcatStrings("Memory ", str,"Management","DynamicMemoryManagement");
    testConcatStrings("Memory", str,"","DynamicMemory");
    testConcatStrings("Memory","" ,"Management","MemoryManagement");
    testConcatStrings("", str,"Management","DynamicManagement");
    testConcatStrings("Memory", "","","Memory");
    testConcatStrings("", str,"",str);
    testConcatStrings("", "","Management","Management");
    testConcatStrings("", "","","");

    return 0;
}

char *concatStrings( char* concaStr,char*str){
    //calculate suze for memory...
    int lenStr=strlen(str);
    int lenConcaStr=strlen(concaStr);
    //+1 byte for 0x00
    int len=lenStr+lenConcaStr+1;
    //reserve memory
    char *result =(char*)malloc(len);
    if (result==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        return -1;
    }
    //concatenate string
    memcpy( result,str,lenStr);
    memcpy( result+lenStr,concaStr,lenConcaStr+1);
    printf("Hoi");
    return result;
}
void concatStrings2( char* newString,char*str){
    //calculate suze for memory...
    int lenStr=strlen(str);
    int lenConcaStr=strlen(newString);
    //+1 byte for 0x00
    int len=lenStr+lenConcaStr+1;
    //reserve memory
    printf("\nLen: %d",len);
    printf(" %s", &newString);
    newString=(char*)realloc(newString,len);
    printf(" %s", &newString);
    if (newString==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(" %s %s ",newString,str);
    //concatenate string
    memcpy(newString+lenConcaStr,str,lenStr+1);
    printf(" %s %s ",newString,str);
}
void testConcatStrings(char* concaStr,char*str, char*str2, char*expected){
    //concatenated string by dynamic memory management(alloc)
    char *result = concatStrings(concaStr,str);
    concatStrings2(result,str2);
        printf(" %s", &result);
    printf("\nstr= %s, concat: %s, str2: %s--> result:%s -->", str,concaStr,str2,result);
    //check result
    (strcmp(result,expected)==0)?printf("Success"): printf("Failure");
    //never forget free!!!!
    free(result);
    printf("\nIs free\n");
}
```

Here the results (it looks messy by I tried to check exactly what happen in there):

```
Hoi
Len: 24 ¿p ¿p DynamicMemory Management  DynamicMemoryManagement Management  ¿p
str= Dynamic, concat: Memory, str2: Management--> result:DynamicMemoryManagement -->Success
Is free
Hoi
Len: 25 ¿p ¿p DynamicMemory  Management  DynamicMemory Management Management  ¿p
str= Dynamic, concat: Memory , str2: Management--> result:DynamicMemory Management -->Failure
Is free
Hoi
Len: 14 ¿p ¿p DynamicMemory   DynamicMemory   ¿p
str= Dynamic, concat: Memory, str2: --> result:DynamicMemory -->Success
Is free
Hoi
Len: 17 êp ¿p Memory Management  MemoryManagement Management  êp
str= , concat: Memory, str2: Management--> result:╚p -->Failure
Is free
Hoi
Len: 18 êp ╚p Dynamic Management  DynamicManagement Management  êp
str= Dynamic, concat: , str2: Management--> result: -->Failure
Is free
Hoi
Len: 7 êp êp Memory   Memory   êp
str= , concat: Memory, str2: --> result:Memory -->Success
Is free
Hoi
Len: 8 êp êp Dynamic   Dynamic   êp
str= Dynamic, concat: , str2: --> result:Dynamic -->Success
Is free
Hoi
Len: 11 êp ░p  Management  Management Management  êp
str= , concat: , str2: Management--> result:╚p -->Failure
Is free
Hoi
Len: 1 Xbp êbp       Xbp
str= , concat: , str2: --> result: -->Success
Is free
```

Comment: Does your compiler not warn about several problems with the code? clang and gcc both do when I run them.

Comment: The other severe mistake in the code is that you're trying to realloc memory that hasn't been allocated using malloc, but rather is static string data.